# Silverlight Grid Column widths

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight 5.0 Grid with three columns, defined with widths `"Auto", "*", and "Auto"`.  Inside the second column, I have another Grid with four columns, defined with width `"25*"`.  Each of these four columns is a ComboBox.

Even though the widths are all defined the same, the ComboBoxes "Auto" size themselves, and when I select one, the box itself narrows to just larger than the down arrow, although the items are sized to fit.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ContentControl Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,1,0,1">
    <ContentPresenter Content="This is a Label" />
</ContentControl>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Name="comboView" FontSize="14" Margin="2,1,2,1" >
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" IsSelected="True" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2" />
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="comboField" FontSize="14" Margin="2,1,2,1" >
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Field1" IsSelected="True" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Field2" />
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
```

...

What have I missed?  When I had just one grid, with the first column set to `Auto` and all the rest set to something like `Width=9*`, the ComboBoxes did not behave this way.

After further observation, it appears that the `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` in the inner grid is the culprit.  If I remove it, the ComboBoxes return to retaining their size, but they take up the whole outer Column 1, when I want them to take up their necessary space and then be centered within the outer Column.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble parsing out what exactly you want.  You want 2 comboBoxes centered in a Grid, taking up only their necessary space?

Comment: @DanTheMan - (There are four ComboBoxes, actually, I just didn't repeat the definitions.)  What I want is three columns (a label, a set of combo boxes, and a button) with the middle column having four combo boxes.  The combo boxes should each be the same width (Width="25*"), altogether taking up only their necessary space, and the four of them then centered in the middle column of the outer grid.

Comment: @Rico - The values with the star are only relative.  It makes no difference whether I use 25* or 0.25*.

Answer (score 0):

If I now understand correctly, your biggest issue is that you want all the comboboxes to be the same width, all taking up the same amount of space (that is: all sized equal to the combobox with the maximum size).  I *believe* you have everything else straightened away.

This would be very easy in WPF; they have a property named '[IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)' which would evenly distribute out the grid width.

There is no such property in Silverlight.  To do this, you're likely going to need to bind the size of each of them and do it in code behind.  It's a bit hacky, but it should work.  Something like this for all of them:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="comboField" FontSize="14" Margin="2,1,2,1" Width="{Binding Path=Width}" SizeChanged="comboField_SizeChanged">
```

Then in code behind:

```
GridLength Width = new GridLength(10);

private void comboField_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewSize.Width > len.Value)
    {
        Width = new GridLength( e.NewSize.Width );
    }
}
```

EDIT:
There's also [this library](http://www.die-rooter.de/ITworks/archives/27-SharedSize-Grid-with-Silverlight.html) that seems to do the same thing you want.

Comment: The issue is not really getting all the comboboxes to be the same width.  I can manage that by setting each ColumnDefinition Width to 1*.  The real issue is in trying to center them within the outer Grid.  If I apply HorizontalAlignment=Center to the inner Grid, the behavior changes from constant Column Widths to variable widths (as if Auto) and the ComboBoxes shrink to minimum width when selected.  This behavior is the same with or without handling SizeChanged.  If I remove the Centering, all the ComboBoxes are uniform in width, but together they take up all the space in the outer grid column

Comment: My current workaround solution is to add two more column definitions, one before the combo boxes and one after.  Setting their widths then gives me "centering" after a fashion; I just have to hard-code the ColumnDefinition widths by trial and error this way.